# difficulties updating to macOS sierra. not enough space to install on my macbook pro

Tags: macos

stuck updating to macOS Sierra.  downloaded fine but when updating computer says i don't have enough space.  and I am now stuck in reboot mode

Comment: Do you have a backup of your computer?